# Unable to connect DB2 instance running in Docker using DBeaver

Tags: docker, db2, dbeaver

I have installed the image ibmcom/db2 on docker running on local Docker Desktop in my Mac. The DB2 instance is up and running.
[DB2 instance in Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWVdw.png)

But when I am trying to connect the DB2 server from DBeaver running in local I am getting following error message.
[DBeaver error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhdzu.jpg)

I know this problem has been solved in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70973863/how-to-connect-to-db2-running-on-docker). However I am still not able to connect the database by following the suggestions given here, e.g. providing userid:password combination. Should I use this combination in user id field or password field, any idea?

Comment: Possibly bad password. So verify. Shell into the container again, and ensure you dot in the ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile .  Then verify the password is valid, by using "db2 connect to TESTCER user db2inst1 using your_password`  (replace your_password by whatever is the password you assigned for the account db2inst1).

Comment: This works!! you were right, probably the password was corrupted. Dropped and recreated the DB2 instance and now the connection works as expected. Thanks!!